# What CSS code do I use to get my webpage to fill the screen on a the iPhone or Android?

Tags: android, iphone, html, css, rendering

I have the HTML code below. I have set the body's width to 640px which is close to what the iPhone's resolution is. However, when I view the webpage on either an iPhone or an Android, it shows up just like it would in my web browser - only taking up part of the screen. The text is so small it's not usable.

What CSS code do I use so that the text stays normal in desktop browsers, but fills the screen on a mobile device? I read some things about using `device-width` properties but I can't get those to work either. What am I doing wrong?

**Note**
I'm not trying to get the red border to stretch all the way across the screen (eg: body:width100%). I just don't understand why the iPhone is not zooming into an area that is set to the same resolution it is supposed to have.

HTML Code:

```
<style>
    body{ width:640px; border: 1px solid red; }
</style>

</head>
<body>
Hello World
</body>
</html>
```

Actual Output:

[image: actual1.jpg]

Desired Output:

[image: desired.jpg]

Comment: use media queries - Responsive Web Design

Comment: can you give an example or how to do this or provide a link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put this in your head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=480">
```

Comment: this is perfect. do you have any good links to articles / tutorials for this and related tricks?

Answer (score 2):

To make the iPhone zoom in on the page, you can use the viewport meta tag.
You can set a scale of 1.0 to make Mobile Safari zoom in on your content exactly, no matter it's actual size.

Here's some documentation on different ways of setting the viewport: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `body { width:100%; border: 1px solid red; }` ?

Comment: yes but the problem is that the text is really small. I only want the width of that box to be 640px or so but I feel like the iPhone should zoom in on it.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use media queries for this.
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/
Example: http://www.alistapart.com/d/responsive-web-design/ex/ex-site-FINAL.html (Resize the page)

A seemingly straight-forward tutorial: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

If you're creating a webapp for iphone, you should really take a look at [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). If you're feeling a bit adventurous, it really is quite easy to use.